# creo que mi ciclo do while se termina sin cumplir mi condicion

Tags: c++

este codigo es un fragmento que utilizo para experimentar de un codigo mas grande  que estoy haciendo que hace el metodo de biseccion pero tengo un ciclo se termina sin cumplir mi condicion pues me parece que ni siquiera hace el calculo de "error" que estan dondetro del if, se supone que deberia de terminar cuan el error es menor de 0.5%

```
float fl(float xl);
float fu(float xu);
float fr(float xr);
int main()
{
    float xl,xu,xr,error=1,j,k=0;
    do
    {
        cout<<"ingrese xl,xu:"<<endl;         //aqui ponga los nuemro 14 y 15 la primera vez
        cin>>xl>>xu;
        xr=(xl+xu)/2;
        if(k>=1)
        {
            error=((xr-j)/xr)*100;           //aqui se supone que tengo que restar (xr(nuevo)-xr(anterior))/xr(nuevo)*100
            if(error<0)
            {
                error=error*(-1);            //y como susupone que es un valor % tiene que ser simpre positivo
            }
        }
        j=xr;
        cout<<xl<<endl;
        cout<<xu<<endl;
        cout<<xr<<endl;
        if(fl(xl)*fr(xr)<0)
        {
            xu=xr;
        }
        else
        {
            xl=xr;
        }
        cout<<xl<<"despues del if"<<endl;           //ahora se ponen los nuevos valores de xl y xu cuando te lo pida en el siguiente ciclo 
        cout<<xu<<"despues del if"<<endl;
        cout<<error<<"error"<<endl;
        cout<<fl(xl)<<endl;                 //los cout son solo una ayuda
        cout<<fu(xu)<<endl;
        cout<<fr(xr)<<endl;
        k=k+1;                   //esto es por que no se me ocurrio otra manera de evitar calcular el error en el primer ciclo
    }
    while(error==0.5);
}
float fl(float xl)
{
    float funcion;
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(3);
    funcion=(((9.8*68.1)/xl)*(1-exp(-(xl/68.1)*10)))-40;
    return funcion; 
} //las otras funciones son igual a esta solo que ahora son con xu y xr
```

si me puede ayudar por favor que llevo toda la tarde :'c

Comment: `se supone que debería de terminar cuan el error es menor de 0.5%` No es así, se termina cuando es exactamente igual a 0.5. Deberás cambiar a while(error<0.5) para para que sea como tú dices. No es buena idea tampoco comparar igualdad contra un float

Comment: si gracias fue un error que se me paso al escribir pero el problema sigue siendo el mismo al copilar me dice que en la primera iteracion el error es 1 (que es como le puse) y de alli se para el while cuando se supone que en la siguente iteracion deveria de ser un error = 1.69

Comment: Pero para que vayamos ordenados, como debería ser ¿ error == 0.5 o error< 0.5 ? Y en todo caso 1.69 no es ni igual ni menor a 0.5. Por eso se sale

Comment: Ahí te respondieron, tienes que pensar en el while como "Mientras se CUMPLA esto, hago esto otro"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El while se repite mientras que la condición se cumpla. Tu estás describiendo la condición para que se pare.

Entonces, al primer ciclo como `error` vale 1, la condición `error == 0.5` ya no se cumple.

Por lo tanto la condición debería ser `!(error <= 0.5)` o `error > 0.5`.

Comment: muchas gracias entonces fue una mala comprencion del do while jeje me sirve

Comment: @Cesar Todos los ciclos se repiten mientras la condición se cumpla. Para que lo tengas en cuenta. Al menos en C++ es así.